# Xamarin Forms Style Toast

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to style a toast in xamarin forms? like changing the corner radius or background color? at least for android.
I am using dependency service to show the toasts an it works fine but I prefer to style the toast a bit. Thanks in advance.

Andorid toast:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageAndroid))]
namespace DeliveryApplication.Droid.DependencyService
{
    class MessageAndroid : IMessage
    {
        public void LongToast(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        public void ShortToast(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Ios Toast:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MessageIOS))] 
namespace DeliveryApplication.Droid.DependencyService
{

    class MessageIOS : IMessage
    {
        const double LONG_DELAY = 3.5;
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

        NSTimer alertDelay;
        UIAlertController alert;
        public void LongToast(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
        }

        public void ShortToast(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        private void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
        {
            alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
            {
                dismissMessage();
            });
            alert = UIAlertController.Create(null, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void dismissMessage()
        {
            if (alert != null)
            {
                alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
            }
            if (alertDelay != null)
            {
                alertDelay.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question linked as duplicate handles native Android case only, where the op seems to be asking about iOS too.

Comment: he said "at least for android".  If he wants to solve for iOS also then he can search for "custom UIAlertController"